# Why a legacy Tapestry 4 page seems to have a limit on number of methods

Tags: java, tapestry

Unfortunately, it's difficult to offer relevant details yet because I don't know what is relevant, so here goes:

I have an old application running on Tapestry 4.  I have a BasePage, with AnotherPage.java inheriting from it.  anotherPage.html uses a variety of custom components as well.

I recently tried to add a couple of methods to BasePage.java, at which point a looped component in AnotherPage.java stopped working properly -- the behavior was very strange.  It seems like the @For loop index was remaining at zero even though the loop executed properly.  I eventually tracked down the problem by process of elimination.  Whenever the number of declared methods between the BasePage and AnotherPage exceeded about 108 methods (including abstract methods), the bug started manifesting.  It didn't seem to matter what the method name was, or whether it was in BasePage or AnotherPage.

I am not sure what question to ask next.  Why is this happening, and what can I look at next to diagnose the problem?

Here is some of the relevant tapestry 4 code from AnotherPage...

```
   <tr jwcid="@For" source="ognl:listDetails" value="ognl:detail" index="ognl:someIndex" volatile="ognl:true">
      <span jwcid="@DetailComponent"  detail="ognl:detail" detailList="ognl:listDetails" detailIndex="ognl:someIndex" ... />
```

The DetailComponent admittedly does things I don't understand.  It in turn includes some type of jwcid="this_or_that@Block" notations (not sure what that means yet), and then within those includes another component:

```
<span jwcid="@GenericDetail"  detail="ognl:detail" 
      detailList="ognl:detailList" ...
      detailIndex="ognl:detailIndex"  />
```

(At any rate, I wish I had time to migrate away from Tapestry 4, but I don't.)

Thanks for any thoughts, suggestions, or just taking the time to read this!

*Note, I have obviously abstracted away some details of the actual system for IP and etc permission reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about Tapestry in particular (boy its been a long time since I used that), but in my JSP days we learned (an even longer time than the Tapestry work) we learned the hard way that Java has a 64K limit on the number of methods in a class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11).  In JSP it came down to `<jsp:include page=””>` vs `<%@ include file=”” %>`.  The "@ include" variant brought the page in at compile time turning it into a method on the JSP being compiled.  The jsp:include variant did not have that behavior.  We just ran around and got rid of all the "@ include" variants and the "too many methods" problem went away.

I suspect in your Tapestry world you are battling against a similar limitation; dependencies your object's are bringing in.  I'm not sure if you can get the intermediate results of compilation of the Tapestry stuff, but you might want to confirm that you aren't going past on of those JVM limitations.

Not much of an answer, I know.  I am prepared to get downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: It's useful to know. I don't see why you should get down-voted for sharing that.  At this point, I will take almost any pointers.  Do you know if tapestry 4 uses compile-time method generation, or reflection?  It seemed to compile fine, but just not run properly.